# how to display different slider arrows on hovering an image?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

how can I make an image gallery in php with slider arrows like this????  [example gallery](http://www.davidchipperfield.co.uk/project/beethoven_festspielhaus)

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make the slider or a way to make the cursor into an arrow

Comment: http://fearlessflyer.com/create-an-awesome-photo-gallery-with-fancybox-and-timthumb/ check this one

Comment: I'm trying to make cursor into arrow on hover..and also trying to make it responsive to arrow keys keyboard ...

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to do this using jQuery carousel for this.

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Comment: ok this is some what helpful..but instead of a lightbox view, have to open it in a page...